# update field when user logs using pdo

Tags: php, pdo

This is my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$now = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'myDB';
$username = 'james';
$paswword = '12345';
$dsn = 'mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='. $dbname;

try  
{  
    $connect = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);  
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);


} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    $message = $e->getMessage()."<br>";
    die();
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM people WHERE email = :email && password = :password';
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute(['email' => $email, 'password' => $pass]);
$result = $stmt->fetch();
if($result)  
{  
        $_SESSION["username"] = $post->firstname;  
        $_SESSION["id"] = $post->id;
        $sql = 'UPDATE people SET last_log_date = :now && WHERE id = :id';
        //error happens here
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(['last_log_date' => $now, 'id' => $_SESSION["id"]]);
        $connect = null;
        header("location:welcome.php");  
}  
else  
{  
        $connect = null;
        $_SESSION["err_msg"] = 'The password or email does not match';
        header("location:loginForm.php");
}

?>
```

My code will check to see if the user logged in correctly but when I go to update the last_log_date I get a fatal error everytime. I don't understand why I cannot update the field after fetching it. The error says something like SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:.

How can I properly update the fields after the user has logged in. Please any help would be appreciated

Comment: So like this?    $stmt->execute(['last_log_date' => now(), 'id' => $_SESSION["id"]]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind the right named parameter which is `now`.

```
 $stmt->execute([':now' => $now, ':id' => $_SESSION["id"]]);
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get an error. Are you sure there is nothing else that may be causing the problem.? Should I make connection null first then reconnect ? The error says there is something wrong with the $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql); after the update query...

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work finally! I was binding it wrong and your answer worked for me after a few tries. Great!

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` before your where clause has nothing to do here. Remove it (check SQL syntax)

Comment: Is `&&` even allowed in MySql, I always thought it was not.

Comment: okay so I delete the &&. I thought I needed it. I am still experiencing the fatal error though.

Comment: It looks like you can use `&&` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and  Who new ... lol ... 8 years and I never use it...